# Sort list by similar element's elements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of posts where each post contains a list of tags. What would be the most efficient way of finding similar posts with regards to tags? That is, how would I sort the list of posts after the number of similar tags they have with the current post?

I have been experimenting with nested for-loops, comparators and hash maps, but I can not figure out what the least time complex way of doing it is.

Comment: Comparator... You are doing it right...

Comment: I agree. Comparator/Comparable is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate similarity of tags for each post in the list with current post - it take linear `O(n)` time and then sort for `O(n log(n))` time so totally your algorithm will work for `O(n log(n))`.

You can not compare similarity without scanning all the tags for all posts and no indexing.

As for indexing - there is a possibility to build i. e. inverted index such as tag -> set of posts and use it to find posts which has the same tags and sort only them (may be you can skip posts which have nothing to do with current - depends on business requirement). But assuming that you still need sorting - it still will be `O(n log(n))` but generally n should be smaller